# How should you backfill a new table in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, query-optimization, rails-activerecord

I'm creating a new table that needs to be backfilled with data based on User accounts (over a couple dozen thousand) with the following one-time rake task.

What I've decided to do is create a big INSERT string for every 2000 users and execute that query.

Here's what the code roughly looks like:

```
task :backfill_my_new_table => :environment do
    inserts = []
    User.find_each do |user|
        tuple = # form the tuple based on user and user associations like (1, 'foo', 'bar', NULL)
        inserts << tuple
    end

    # At this point, the inserts array is of size at least 20,000
    conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
    inserts.each_slice(2000) do |slice|
        sql = "INSERT INTO my_new_table (ref_id, column_a, column_b, column_c) VALUES #{inserts.join(", ")}"
        conn.execute(sql)
    end
end
```

So I'm wondering, is there a better way to do this? What are some drawbacks of the approach I took? How should I improve it? What if I didn't slice the `inserts` array and simply executed a single `INSERT` with over a couple dozen thousand VALUES tuples? What are the drawbacks of that method?

Thanks!

Comment: Why wouldn't you use MyNewTable methods wrapped in a transaction to speed up the inserts? Also, current implementation opens you up to SQL injection.

Comment: Oh, I missed you're doing multiple inserts at once. That would indeed be faster (but not sure how much if you wrapped normal inserts in a transaction of say 1000 each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on which PG version you are using, but in most cases of bulk loading data to a table this is enough checklist:

- try to use [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html) instead of INSERT whenever possible;
- if using multiple INSERTs, disable autocommit and wrap all INSERTs in a single transaction, i.e. `BEGIN; INSERT ...; INSERT ...; COMMIT;`
- disable indexes and checks/constraints on/of a target table;
- disable table triggers;
- [alter table](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/interactive/sql-altertable.html) so it became [unlogged](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/interactive/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-UNLOGGED) (since PG 9.5, don't forget to turn logging on after data import), or increase [max_wal_size](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-MAX-WAL-SIZE) so [WAL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/interactive/wal-intro.html) wont be flooded

20k of rows is not such a big deal for a PG, so 2k-sliced inserts within one transaction will be just fine, unless there are some **very complex** triggers/checks involved. It is also worth reading [PG manual section on bulk loading](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/populate.html).

UPD: and [a little bit old, yet wonderful piece from depesz](http://www.depesz.com/2007/07/05/how-to-insert-data-to-database-as-fast-as-possible/), excerpt:

> so, if you want to insert data as fast as possible – use copy (or better yet – pgbulkload). if for whatever reason you can't use copy, then use multi-row inserts (new in 8.2!). then if you can, bundle them in transactions, and use prepared transactions, but generally – they don't give you much.